# swift collection view resizing problems

Tags: swift, uicollectionview

So the problem which I have is, the collection view, depending on what simulator I am using it displays either 3(iPhone 5) columns in one setting or 4 columns(iPhone 6) in another. I want the collection view to always displays 4 columns no matter how big or small the screen is. Here is some code I am using so far:

```
 override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    let screenWidth = UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds.size.width
    let screenHeight = UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds.size.height


    let layout: UICollectionViewFlowLayout = UICollectionViewFlowLayout()
    layout.sectionInset = UIEdgeInsets(top: 20, left: 10, bottom: 10, right: 10)
    layout.itemSize = CGSize(width: 100, height: 80)

           collview1 = UICollectionView(frame: CGRectMake(0, 0, screenWidth, screenHeight), collectionViewLayout: layout)


    [collview1.reloadData];


}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll want to change your layout.itemSize to a calculated value.

Something like:

```
layout.itemSize = CGSize(width: (screenWidth - spacing) / numberOfColumns, height: desiredHeight)
```

Spacing would be the total inter item spacing in a row plus the left and right insets.

DesiredHeight should probably be a calculated value to maintain the aspect ratio of your cells between devices.

Hopefully that's helpful.